# Any recommendation after Google site search got discontinued?

Tags: google, search

> Google has discontinued sale/renewal of the Google Site Search since Apr 1 2017. The product will be completely shut down by April 1, 2018.

Source: https://enterprise.google.com/search/products/gss.html

Now the Google Site Search is discontinued, is there a replacement?

Comment: Google Custom Search Engine (CSE) https://cse.google.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CSE](https://cse.google.com/cse/). It is a platform provided by Google that allows web developers to feature specialized information in web searches, refine and categorize queries and create customized search engines, based on Google Search.